# findElement is able to identify an element whereas findElements stops the execution

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

the below code stops the execution

```
if(driver.findElements(By.id("create")).size() > 0) {
    ...
}
```

whereas the below code works without an issue

```
if(driver.findElement(By.id("create")).isDisplayed()) {
    ...
}
```

Whenever findElements is used, the script execution stops

Answer (score 0):

you are missing a bracket. try this:

```
if(driver.findElements(By.id("create")).size() > 0)
```